# JAVA - How to fetch the about to run test module name in @BeforeClass method of junit

Tags: java, junit

In my setup method of `@BeforeClass` method, I want to fetch the name of the module which is about to run. 
For example, i ran the Login Module, so in the static `@BeforeClass` I want the name of the module `Login` so that I can set that in the capabilities
Also the `@BeforeClass` method is in parent class, say `BaseTest.java`,  and the `@test` method is present in the child class. So as per my example Login class is a child class and `BaseTest.java` is the parent Class.

[Project Modules Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTp8A.png)

Comment: What do you call a "Module"? The name of the project? The name of the current class? The current class would simply be `getClass().getSImpleName()`, but I doubt that's what you are asking for...

Comment: could you add some section of the classes to remove doubts on the question please

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz I have added the screenshot _Project Modules Screenshot_ where you can see that i have different java classes for different modules. So, here `BaseTest.java` and `LoginTest.java` both are java classes.

Comment: In that case, I suggest simply using `getClass().getSimpleName()`, which will return `ConferenceBridgingTest`, `ContactsTest`, etc. depending in which test you are. (without "Simple", just `getName()` it will return the qualified classname, which includes the package name).

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz I cannot call getClass() function from a static context. `@BeforeClass` function must be a static function in Junit

Answer (score -1):

You can try code like below:

```
  @BeforeClass
  public void beforeClass(ITestContext result) {
      System.out.println("method name:" + result.getCurrentXmlTest().getName());  
  }
```

[More detail](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependency-injection)

Comment: @Sadik In Junit, we cannot have a `@BeforeClass` method without `static ` and also we cannot pass in parameters in `@BeforeClass` method